# If $\sin x - \cos x = \frac{1}{2}$ then determine: $\sin^4 x + \cos^4 x$

Tags: trigonometry

If $$\sin x - \cos x = \frac{1}{2}$$ then determine: $$\sin^4 x + \cos^4 x$$
I tried making it $(\sin^2 x)^2+(\cos^2 x)^2$ but then I get nothing that can help. What is the trick to this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have
$$
\frac{1}{4}=(\sin x-\cos x)^2=\sin^2x-2\sin x\cos x+\cos^2x
$$
so
$$
\sin x\cos x=\frac{1}{2}\left(1-\frac{1}{4}\right)=\frac{3}{8}
$$
Then
$$
\sin^4x+\cos^4x=(\sin^2x+\cos^2x)^2-\dotsb
$$

Comment: I actually don't understand... I am lost after the determining of $\sin x \cos x = \frac {3}{8}$

Comment: @RiktasMath Do you know what the parenthesis reduces to?$$\frac14=\sin^2x-2\sin x\cos x+\cos^2x=(\sin^2x+\cos^2x)-2\sin x\cos x$$

Comment: @RiktasMath $(a+b)^2=a^2+2ab+b^2$, so $a^2+b^2=(a+b)^2-2ab$; use $a=\sin^2x$ and $b=\cos^2x$.

Answer (score 1):

I'm using the identity $2(u^2+v^2)=(u+v)^2+(u-v)^2$ repeatedly:
$$(\cos x+\sin x)^2=2(\cos^2 x+\sin^2 x)-(\cos x-\sin x)^2=2-\frac14=\frac74,$$ so
\begin{align}2(\cos^4 x+\sin^4 x)&=(\cos^2 x+\sin^2 x)^2+(\cos^2 x-\sin^2 x)^2\\&=(\cos^2 x+\sin^2 x)^2+(\cos x+\sin x)^2\,(\cos x-\sin x)^2\\&=1+\frac74\cdot\frac14=\frac{23}{16}\end{align} We get $$\cos^4 x+\sin^4 x=\frac{23}{32}.$$

Comment: I actually don't understand... I am lost after the determining $\sin x \cos x = \frac {3}{8}$

Comment: @RiktasMath I didn't determine $\sin x \cos x = \frac {3}{8}$.

Comment: Posted the comment by accident on your answer. Tbh I don't get anything on your answer...

Comment: @RiktasMath You're welcome. It happens often on this site that people ask questions, but don't understand the answers.

Comment: You are using identities I have never seen in my life. Not everyone here is a professor or college student. I am a normal high school student trying to learn something. Thanks!

Comment: hmmm, the only identities used in Vector's answer are $sin^2x+cos^2x=1$ and simply FOIL to get $(u+v)^2=u^2+2uv+v^2$ and $(u-v)^2=u^2-2uv+v^2$. For a high school student rather standard...